# Python Curve fit, gaussian

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to gauss fit my data using scipy and curve fit, here is my code :

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

A=[]
T=[]
seuil=1000
range_gauss=4
a=0

pos_peaks=[]
amp_peaks=[]

A_gauss=[]
T_gauss=[]

new_A=[]
new_T=[]

def gauss(x,a,x0,sigma):
  return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

with open("classeur_test.csv",'r') as csvfile:
  reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader :
  A.append(float(row[0]))
  T.append(float(row[1]))

npA=np.array(A)
npT=np.array(T)

for i in range(1,len(T)):
  #PEAK DETECTION
  if (A[i]>A[i-1] and A[i]>A[i+1]) and A[i]>seuil:
    pos_peaks.append(i)
    amp_peaks.append(A[i])
    #GAUSSIAN RANGE
    for j in range(-range_gauss,range_gauss):
        #ATTENTION AUX LIMITES
        if(i+j>0 and i+j<len(T)-1):
            A_gauss.append(A[i+j])
            T_gauss.append(T[i+j])

npA_gauss = np.array(A_gauss)
npT_gauss = np.array(T_gauss)

for i in range (0,7):
  new_A.append(npA_gauss[i])
  new_T.append(npT_gauss[i])

new_npA=np.array(new_A)
new_npT=np.array(new_T)

n = 2*range_gauss
mean = sum(new_npT*new_npA)/n
sigma = sum(new_npA*(new_npT-mean)**2)/n

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss,new_npT,new_npA,p0=[1,mean,sigma])
plt.plot(T,A,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(new_npT,gauss(new_npT,*popt),'ro:',label='Fit')

print ("new_npA : ",new_npA)
print ("new_npT : ",new_npT)

plt.legend()
plt.title('Fit')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

My arrays `new_npT` and `new_npA` are numpy arrays like this :

`new_npA :  [ 264.  478.  733. 1402. 1337.  698.  320.]`

`new_npT :  [229.609344 231.619385 233.62944  235.639496 237.649536 239.659592
 241.669647]`

This is the result

[image]

I don't understand why I can't successfully plot the gauss curves...
Any explanations?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a copypastable piece of code, including the imports. I don't know what `range_gauss`, `A` and `T` are…

Comment: Indeed, sorry i just changed this

Comment: Your initial guess (i.e. p0) is just way off. The best fit values are popt = [1385.69624869,  236.42154954,    3.01765803] as one can roughly guess from your image. Your initial guess was [1, 154413, 15545866284717] so especially sigma was off almost 13 orders of magnitude. Your mistake is when you calculate mean and sigma you assume that new_npA is a probability distribution, which it is not because it is not normalized.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! It seems that the gaussian fits... How did you calculate these values ? I don't understand your numbers.

Comment: @KarlMontalban I just changed the inital guess in your code to something reasonable like popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss,new_npT,new_npA,p0=[1400,240,10])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now fit gaussians curves on my data

I still can't understand how Jannick found the `p0` for the curve fit, but it works.

I created a 3 dimensional array with positions and amplitudes of peaks and used a `while` loop for the `rang_gauss`. I used the scipy `curve_fit` properly with my 3D array, and corrected the amplitudes with a coefficient `f`.

[image]

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
seuil=1000 # calculer en fonction du bruit etc ................................
range_gauss=4

A=[]
T=[]

pos_peaks=[]
amp_peaks=[]
indices_peaks=[]

tab_popt=[]
l=[] 
gauss_result=[]

tab_w=[]

def gauss1(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

def gauss2(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return (a/sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-0.5*((x-x0)/sigma)**2)

#LECTURE DU FICHIER ET INITIALISATION DE TABLEAUX CONTENANT TOUTES LES VALEURS
with open("classeur_test.csv",'r') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader :
        A.append(float(row[0]))
        T.append(float(row[1]))

#PEAK DETECTION
for i in range(1,len(T)):
    if (A[i]>A[i-1] and A[i]>A[i+1]) and A[i]>seuil:
        pos_peaks.append(T[i])
        amp_peaks.append(A[i])
        indices_peaks.append(i)

#TABLEAU 3D AVEC LES AMPLITUDES ET TEMPS DE CHAQUE PIC
Tableau=np.zeros((len(pos_peaks),2,2*range_gauss+1))

#POUR CHAQUE PIC
m=0
j=-range_gauss
for i in range(0,len(pos_peaks)):
    while(j<range_gauss+1):
        #PEAK DETECTION & LIMITS CONSIDERATION
        if(pos_peaks[i]+j>=0 and pos_peaks[i]+j<=T[len(T)-1] and m<=2*range_gauss+1 and indices_peaks[i]+j>=0):  
            Tableau[i,0,m]=(A[indices_peaks[i]+j])
            Tableau[i,1,m]=(T[indices_peaks[i]+j]) 
            m=m+1
            j=j+1
        else :
            j=j+1
            print("else")
            print("1 : ",pos_peaks[i]+j,", m : ",m," , indices_peaks[i]+j : ",indices_peaks[i]+j)
    m=0
    j=-range_gauss

    popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss2,Tableau[i,1,:],Tableau[i,0,:],p0=[[1400,240,10]])
    tab_popt.append(popt)
    l.append(np.linspace(T[indices_peaks[i]-range_gauss],T[indices_peaks[i]+range_gauss],50))

    gauss_result.append(gauss2(l[i],1,tab_popt[i][1],tab_popt[i][2])*(1))
    f= amp_peaks[i]/max(gauss_result[i])
    gauss_result[i]=gauss_result[i]*f

    #LARGEUR MI HAUTEUR
    w=2*np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))*tab_popt[i][2]
    tab_w.append(w)

    ####################################PLOTS
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(T,A,label='data')
    plt.axis([T[0]-5,T[len(T)-1]-10,0,max(A)+200])
    #plt.plot(Tableau[i,1,:],gauss2(Tableau[i,1,:],*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(l[i],gauss_result[i])
    plt.axis([T[0]-5,T[len(T)-1]-10,0,max(A)+200])

'''TEST POINTS INFLEXIONS
    for j in range(0,len(A)-1):
        inflex_points.append((np.diff(np.diff(A[j],n=2),n=2)))
        print(inflex_points[j])

        for k in range(0,len(inflex_points[j])-1):
            if (inflex_points[j][k] < 1 and inflex_points[j][k] > -1):
                print("j : ",j)'''

'''TEST INTERNET GRADIENT ???
plt.plot(np.gradient(gauss_result[0]), '+')
spl = UnivariateSpline(np.arange(len(gauss_result[0])), np.gradient(gauss_result[0]), k=5)
spl.set_smoothing_factor(1000)
plt.plot(spl(np.arange(len(gauss_result[0]))), label='Smooth Fct 1e3')
spl.set_smoothing_factor(10000)
plt.plot(spl(np.arange(len(gauss_result[0]))), label='Smooth Fct 1e4')
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
max_idx = np.argmax(spl(np.arange(len(gauss_result[0]))))
plt.vlines(max_idx, -5, 9, linewidth=5, alpha=0.3)
'''

plt.show()
```